# Video.js live stream setup: help request

Tags: javascript, video.js, mpeg, mp4box, dash.js

I'm working with mpeg dash to stream live between mp4box and dash.js. The problem arises on the client side when the user pauses for too long time the playhead tries to read a point where the buffer has already passed.
I'can't find how to get a live skin without play pause or seekbar, actually i try video.js to customise the interface, i use the standard configuration, and css configuration don't give me what i need, i wish to know if there is an easy opensource way to display live streaming.
Thanks a lot,
Massimo

Comment: I'd suggest you point us to your real-world URL where you are trying this, if you expect help for your stated problem.  (To stream "between mp4box and dash.js, using video.js" is way too abstract of a notion to mean anything to any one individual.) Ditto for "opensource way to display live streaming".

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry i try to explain better my self cause at the moment there is not a test on internet but only on local network.
I use MP4Box to generate mpeg dash manifest and segments over and over for live stream.
I use Dash.js to reach the mpeg dash buffer processed by MP4Box,
The mpd is profile live dynamic.
The problem is that i can't understand which door i have to knock to obtain a live skin for the player, MP4Box 4 wrong mpd configuration? Dash.js possible live setup? or i need to use an opensource html5 player such video.js and modify it for my scope and use it with Dash.js.